# lua nested json array not accepted without extra comma

Tags: json, linux, lua

I installed lua like this on linux

```
sudo apt install lua5.3 lua-socket lua-json
```

I have the following lua program:

```
local json = require("json")
local payload = [[{
  "a": ["c","d"],
  "b": [[2.2,3.3],[4.4,5.5],],
  "debug": true
}]]
print(payload)
```

<s>local ptest = json.encode( payload )
print (ptest)</s>

note that line "b" is invalid json because of the extra comma after the second nested array - but removing that comma causes lua to error out, like this:

```
lua: test.lua:5: unexpected symbol near ':'
```

here are a few more versions of line b - in all cases, lua errors out on the valid versions and accepts the invalid json version (with the extra comma after the last nested array)

```json
"b": [[[2.2],[3.3]],4.4,5.5], // valid
"b": [[[2.2],[3.3],],4.4,5.5], // invalid
"b": [[2.2,3.3],[4.4,5.5]], // valid
"b": [[2.2,3.3],[4.4,5.5],], //invalid
"b": [[[2.2],[3.3],],[[4.4],[5.5],],], // invalid
```

is there a setting to get lua to accept the valid json? maybe I have the wrong version or am missing something obvious?

the program can be saved in a text file named test.lua and run at the commandline like this:

```
lua test.lua
```

Comment: The conversion from JSON string into Lua object is **decoding**, so why do you invoke `json.encode`?

Comment: @ESkri you are correct the json.encode is not needed for printing the string, I updated the question with a direct print() statement. The problem is that lua accepts only the invalid json with the extra comma, which would cause an internal server error http 500 if I were to get as far as sending this as a POST request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [3.1 – Lexical Conventions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.1) *(emphasis mine)*:

> Literal strings can also be defined using a long format enclosed by long brackets. We define an opening long bracket of level n as an opening square bracket followed by n equal signs followed by another opening square bracket. So, an opening long bracket of level 0 is written as [[, an opening long bracket of level 1 is written as [=[, and so on. A closing long bracket is defined similarly; for instance, a closing long bracket of level 4 is written as ]====]. A long literal starts with an opening long bracket of any level and ends at the first closing long bracket of the same level. **It can contain any text except a closing bracket of the same level.**

So the trailing comma is preventing Lua from otherwise parsing a matching *closing long bracket* (`]]`).

Use a different *level* of long bracket so that your JSON string can contain nested arrays.

```lua
local payload = [=[{
  "a": ["c","d"],
  "b": [[2.2,3.3],[4.4,5.5]],
  "debug": true
}]=]

print(payload)
```

Result:

```json
{
  "a": ["c","d"],
  "b": [[2.2,3.3],[4.4,5.5]],
  "debug": true
}
```